# Search part of a QString in QStringList in Qt

Tags: c++, qt

In QString, contains() method works like this:

```
QString s = "long word";
s.contains("long"); // -> True
```

I would assume that QStringList works similarly, but it does not:

```
QStringList s;
s << "long word";
s << "longer word";
s.contains("long"); // -> False
```

QStringList contains searches for the exact match, which does not work like I want it to. Is there an easy way to find a part of a string in a QStringList? I could of course loop through the QStringList and use contains() there, but is there a better way?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can use the function [QStringList::filter()](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qstringlist.html#filter) :

> QStringList QStringList::filter(const QString &str,
>   Qt::CaseSensitivity cs = Qt::CaseSensitive) const
>
> Returns a list of all the strings containing the substring str.

and check that the list returned is not empty.

In your case:

```
QStringList s;
s << "long word";
s << "longer word";
s.filter("long"); // returns "long word", and also "longer word" since "longer" contains "long"
```

Comment: Actually it's returning both QStrings since "long" is also a substring of "longer. :)

Comment: Of course :) but it answers the question *Is there an easy way to find a part of a string in a QStringList?*

Comment: Yes, I was not referring to your solution but just to your comment '// returns "long word"'. :).